# Deciding the major product in this Wurtz reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, halides

Today I was told:

> When 2-chlorobutane is reacted with 2-chloropropane in the presence of sodium and dry ether the following products are formed:

- 2,3-dimethylpentane
- 3,4-dimethylhexane
- 2,3-dimethylbutane

> 3,4-dimethylhexane, being most symmetric, is the major product.

I'm not satisfied with the reason provided. Can anyone please explain the fact in a better manner?

---

What I'm unable to understand is that both 3,4-dimethylhexane and 2,3-dimethylbutane and equally symmetric since both have a plane of symmetry, don't they? Then how are we using symmetry to compare the yield?

Comment: What part of it didn't you understand? You may get better answers if you exactly point that out.

Comment: "2,3-dimethylhexane, being most symmetric, is the major product." 2,3-dimethylhexane is not an expected product, do you mean 2,3-dimethylbutane?  Were the starting materials present in equimolar amounts?

Comment: @ron I think OP meant 2,3-dimethylpentane, which would statistically be the major product if the starting materials are present in equimolar amounts. (That has nothing to do with symmetry... so I don't know what OP was told.)

Comment: @ron the OP had it right then did an edit.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion here, it's actually 3,4 and not 2,3. :)

Comment: I've edited the question, @M.A.Ramezani

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that there should be a 'statistical product distribution', if I'm correct the products should be in the ratios 2:1:1.

You get to this conclusion as follows, call 2-chlorobutane A and 2-chloropropane B.

A can react with A to give AA, and
A can react with B to give AB, while
B can react with A to give BA, while
B can react with B to give BB.

When you realise that AB and BA are the same molecule you get AA:2AB:BB; that is, 1:2:1.

Comment: +1 Then, is symmetry responsible for anything here?

Comment: Not as far as I can see.